# "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions." with react/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I've encountered this error and spent the last few hours trying to figure it out. I've looked at all the questions that appear to be duplicates - but they don't solve the issue.

In my react/redux app, when I made an ajax request in one of my actions, it throws this error out:
`Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

My store creation looks like this:

```js
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import reducers from './reducers';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';

export default createStore(reducers, composeWithDevTools(
 applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
));
```

The relevant reducer looks like this:

```js
import * as actions from './../../actions/tools/vehicle-lookup';

const defaultState = {
 vrm: void 0,
 isLoading: false,
 response: void 0,
 error: void 0,
};

export default function (state = defaultState, action) {
 switch (action.type) {
  case actions.VEHICLE_LOOKUP:
   return { ...state, isLoading: true, vrm: action.vrm };

  case actions.VEHICLE_LOOKUP_SUCCESS:
   return { ...state, isLoading: false, payload: action.payload, error: void 0 };

  case actions.VEHICLE_LOOKUP_FAILURE:
   return { ...state, isLoading: false, error: action.error, response: void 0 };

  default: return state;
 }
}
```

The relevant action looks like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const VEHICLE_LOOKUP = 'VEHICLE_LOOKUP';
export const VEHICLE_LOOKUP_SUCCESS = 'VEHICLE_LOOKUP_SUCCESS';
export const VEHICLE_LOOKUP_FAILURE = 'VEHICLE_LOOKUP_FAILURE';

export function fetchVehicleLookup(vrm: string, jwt: string) {
 return function (dispatch) {
  dispatch(requestVehicleLookup());

  axios.create({
   timeout: 4000,
  })
   .post('/*api url*', {
    action: '*method*',
    body: { vrm },
   })
   .then(response => response.data)
   .then(json => dispatch(receiveVehicleData(json)))
   .catch(error => dispatch(receiveVehicleDataFailure(error)));
 };
}

function requestVehicleLookup() {
 return { type: VEHICLE_LOOKUP };
}

function receiveVehicleData(payload: object) {
 return { type: VEHICLE_LOOKUP_SUCCESS, payload };
}

function receiveVehicleDataFailure(error: object) {
 return { type: VEHICLE_LOOKUP_FAILURE, error };
}
```

My package versions are:

```
"axios": "^0.16.0",
"react": "^15.4.2",
"react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.5.0",
"react-addons-transition-group": "^15.5.0",
"react-dom": "^15.4.2",
"react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
"react-redux": "^5.0.3",
"react-router": "^4.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.0",
"redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
"redux-promise-middleware": "^4.2.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
```

Comment: Can you also include the code where your async action is being dispatched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out - after a very long chat with @Glitch100 (thanks!). I needed to return the dispatch of requestVehicleLookup just after the axios promise was created. Like so:

```js
export function fetchVehicleLookup(vrm: string, jwt: string) {
 return function (dispatch) {
  axios.create({
   timeout: 4000,
  })
   .post('/*api url*', {
    action: '*method*',
    body: { vrm },
   })
   .then(response => response.data)
   .then(json => dispatch(receiveVehicleData(json)))
   .catch(error => dispatch(receiveVehicleDataFailure(error)));
      
      
  return dispatch(requestVehicleLookup());
 };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First thought was that your `fetchVehicleLookup` action was moaning because you are returning the `axios` instead of just dispatching within.

```
export function fetchVehicleLookup(vrm: string, jwt: string) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(requestVehicleLookup());

        axios.create({
            timeout: 4000,
        })
            .post('/*api url*', {
                action: '*method*',
                body: { vrm },
            })
            .then(response => response.data)
            .then(json => dispatch(receiveVehicleData(json)))
            .catch(error => dispatch(receiveVehicleDataFailure(error)));
    };
}
```

Simply remove the `return` statement that is in your action, as it's returning whatever object axios represents, which I imagine is going to be some form of `Promise`.

Second thought could be something around your store setup because it sounds like `thunk` isn't actually working.

Comment: I've removed that return from axios, and the same error is still present sadly - will edit to remove from my op

Comment: For the sake of testing remove the entire `axios` section, and just dispatch  a dummy action instead. Is the error still present?